# Values from the Intent is not showing

Tags: android, android-intent

I don't know what I did wrong over here. I have followed the tutorial but my values end up being empty.

**Passsing values to the Intent**

```
ListView lvItems = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvDashboardCompleted);
        lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast shows the id over here
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), categoryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_ID", id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Reviving value from the Intent**

```
public class categoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        String recevied_cat_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("CATEGORY_ID");

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = recevied_cat_id;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You pass a `long` value, but retrieved `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace `onCreate` method. What was the issue? As @ARiF has highlighted correctly, you are passing long from your Intent but in your method you are retrieving the String.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        Long recevied_cat_id = getIntent().getLongExtra("CATEGORY_ID", 1L);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String strLong = Long.toString(recevied_cat_id);
        CharSequence text = strLong;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `String recevied_cat_id = getIntent().getLongExtra("CATEGORY_ID", defaultLongValue);` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much